# Git branches with some common content and some not

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have a codebase that is x-platform. I manage most build related mechanics with CMake, allowing me to work on the same content when working in linux or windows (VisualStudio).

However, I do also compile the codebase using borland tools. The borland IDE uses .cbproj files to handle a project.

Within the codebase there are hundreds of small subprojects, meaning hundreds of cbproj files.

Question is, is it possible to setup a repository with a develop branch, containing all common files for the code base and another branch, say borland_develop, that reflect(kept synced with) the develop branch, but in addition contain the extra cbproj files??

Goal is to be able to automatically merge the borland_develop into develop, without having to pay extra attention to the cbproj files.

Comment: Thanks for the link, however, that post seem to use a technique of ignoring certain files. In my case, the project files still need to be tracked.

Comment: After trying the instructions from the link, I was unable to get it to work on my local machine, the ignored files would be pulled down or merged and there does not seem to be any way to exclude them. I've deleted the incorrect answer. Sorry :(

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Maybe if there would be some kind of `pre-merge` hook it would be possible to remove the `cbproj` files, but git doesn't provide such a hook.